# Ansible "service" call mysteriously succeeds without sudo

Tags: ansible

Managing services with systemctl requires me to sudo:

*admin> sudo systemctl start foo*

However, ansible magically succeeds with no explicit sudo reference:

```
- hosts: targets   
  remote_user: admin
  become: yes   
  service: name=foo state=started
```

Is "become" an implicit request to sudo the service invocation?

Answer (score -1):

The **become** directive enables "privilege escalation" (not particularly accurate but that's what they called it).

The reason **become** alone appears to work is that the **become_method** defaults to **sudo** and the **become_user** defaults to the **remote_user**.